# Can I access excel mathematical functions from flex action script through vbscript injection?

Tags: apache-flex, math, vbscript

We are looking to do display some mathematical data in a Flex GUI chart. We need to do plot for two array of data the following.

cross-correlation of both
auto-correaltion of each
and correlation coefficient

It looks like Flex does not support scientific formula like cross-correlation,auto-correlation and co-relation co-efficient natively. **Please correct me if I am wrong or if there are reasonable alternatives at this point.**

While looking for alternatives I did come across the article at actionscript.org
[--not allowed--]

and I am presently trying to see whether I can invoke excel formulas from the actionscript. It looks like there might be some complexity involved in passing the data between flex and vbscript. **Will this be the right approach?**

This is for a POC and as such we are looking for a quick hack only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably way too late, but, well...I got bored :)

`private function correlationCoeff(X:Array, Y:Array):Number
{
    //correlation coeff between two random variables X and Y is defined as :
    //correlation(X,Y) = Covar(X,Y)/(sqrt(Var(X)) * sqrt(Var(Y)))
    //
    //Var(X) = Covar(X,X);
    //Covar(X,Y) = E((X-xm)(Y-ym)); where xm, ym are the population means.
    return sampleCovar(X, Y)/Math.sqrt(sampleCovar(X, X) * sampleCovar(Y, Y));
}`

private function sampleCovar(X:Array, Y:Array):Number
{
    //Sample covariance is Sum((X-xm)(Y-ym))/n-1
    //where n is the sample size and xm & ym are sample means.
    //I'll assume that X and Y are the same size...
    var total:Number = 0;
    var xm:Number = sampleMean(X);
    var ym:Number = (X == Y)? xm : sampleMean(Y);
    for (var i:int=0; i

private function sampleMean(X:Array):Number
{
    //Sample mean = Sum(X)/(sample size)
    var total:Number = 0;
    for each(var x:Number in X)
        total += x;
    return total/X.length;
}

I did rather assume you were working with discrete random variables as opposed to doing something funky with signal processing. Bear in mind that sampleCovar won't return the same thing as COVAR in Excel, because Excel uses the biased estimator (i.e. it divides by n rather than (n-1)), but this cancels out when calculating the correlation coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used VBScript, but I know that you can access JavaScript from AS3 and vice versa using the `ExternalInterface` class in AS3.  And as far as I know, you can also access VB functions embedded in web pages from JavaScript. So, it shouldn't be too hard to invoke VB functions from Flash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason I wanted to use VBScript is to try and use the Excel methods like COREL(A[],B[]) from flex. So it is more of an excel call than a VB call. Not sure whether that can be done easily.

For now, we are going ahead and started coding the formula directly in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Using ActionScript you can write your own version of COREL to do the calculation.  That will be much easier than trying to communicate with Excel.  Certainly there is no direct way to communicate with Excel from a Flex app.